# Find coordinates from a contour in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, curve-fitting, contour

I suppose this is not something difficult but i wonder if there is any function or any optimal way.

Consider that after an image process i have a matrix-image  with 0 everywhere and 1 at the contour.

Now i want to **find the x y along that contour line**
The important is that eg   **[ x(2) y(2) ]**   should be the next pixel to **[x(1) y(1)]**

I have used this:

**[c h]=contour(image,1)**

**x=c(1,:) 
y=c(2,:)**

But the result is not very good and it gives some noise points which is very bad (and for some reason it appears mirrored)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted my complete solution to help other people:

*Problem:*

I have a grayscale image and i want to find the coordinates **X Y in order** along the **contour** .

*Solution:*

Set a threshold for black and white and make the image binary (optional)

```
`image=image>0.5 %This is optional but some may found it usefull`
```

**Find the Start Point:**

```
[yStart xStart]=find(image,1);
```

This will scan the image  column by column from left to right and up to down and will return the first **non zero** pixel. So this will return the 'left-est up' pixel of the image. Remember, X is the column and Y is the row. Zero is at the top-left corner!

**Find the contour:**

```
contour=bwtraceboundary(image, [yStart, xStart],'NE');
```

or

```
contour = bwtraceboundary(image,[yStart xStart],'NE',8,Inf,'clockwise');
```

NE is the initial direction (NorthEast)

```
x=contour(:,2)
y=contour(:,1)
```

If the point [yStart xStart] is not on the contour of an image this will not work !

If you plot (x,y) that will be mirrored. This is because the zero at the coordinate system is at the top left corner of the image and not at the bottom left. To do it properly you can do this:

```
y=-y
y=y+abs(min(y))+1 % +1 is to avoid y=0
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have the image processing toolbox, I highly suggest using [`bwperim`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwperim.html) which returns a `logical` image where `true` is a perimeter or contour point and `false` otherwise.... not to mention that it's faster.

Try doing:

```
bw = bwperim(image == 1); % image == 1 to ensure binary
[y, x] = find(bw);
```

The first line of code finds an image that only contains contour points, and we can use `find` after that on the result to find the row and column locations.  Here `y` represents the row and `x` represents the column locations.

If you desire that the contour is **ordered**, then use the [`bwtraceboundary`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwtraceboundary.html) function instead.  However, this will require that you specify an initial contour point prior to running the function.

An easy way to do this would be to find any non-zero point along the contour of your object.  You could use `bwperim` first and sample any point from here.  Choosing just any point may not give you an actual contour point.

Therefore:

```
bw = bwperim(image == 1); % image == 1 to ensure binary
[y, x] = find(bw, 1); % Find the first contour point
ctr = bwtraceboundary(image == 1, [y, x], 'SE');
```

`'SE'` is the direction of where to look first given the initial contour point. Here I've chosen south east. This will produce a `N x 2` matrix where the first column contains the rows and second column contains the columns of the ordered contour points starting at the initial position provided by `y` and `x`.

Comment: `find` will sort the pixels in indexing order, and will not trace the contour. [`bwtraceboundary`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwtraceboundary.html) is the function to use here.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I didn't realize the OP wanted ordered points.  I didn't assume so, but I'll add this in.

Comment: Thank both of you! I use Matlab R2016a so this does not work , use this instead:
contour=bwtraceboundary(image, [y, x], 'SE')   or

contour = bwtraceboundary(image ,[y x],'SE',8,Inf,'counterclockwise');